# Details: Appium's IosDriver does not support xcode version 8.3.2

Tags: ios, ruby, mobile, cucumber, appium-ios

I am having difficulties running a mobile automated test.
I get the following error

`A new session could not be created. Details: Appium's IosDriver does not support xcode version 8.3.2. Apple has deprecated UIAutomation. Use the "XCUITest" automationName capability instead. (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::SessionNotCreatedError)`

I am currently using Xcode version 8.3.2 and Appium version 1.0.0.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

In Xcode 8, UIAutomation is deprecated and it supports XCUITest. So if you have written the desired capability for automation name as UI Automation, change it to:

```
desiredcapabilities.setCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");
```

Also, Xcode 8+ works only with appium 1.6+. So upgrade your Appium to the latest version.

Ref: https://github.com/appium/appium-dot-app/issues/575

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: A minor but important detail, the capability is "automationName" (lower case 'a')

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that the IosDriver is deprecated. Take a look here: https://discuss.appium.io/t/xcodebuild-failed-with-code-65-warning-the-server-did-not-provide-any-stacktrace-information-command-duration-or-timeout-32-63-seconds/12756/4

Comment: Thank you so much!